# redirect_to method does not work in create method (Rails 7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I would like that the user is redirected to the root_path if the submission of the form fails.

Here's my create method:

```
  def create
    @entertainment = Entertainment.new(entertainment_params)
    @entertainment.user = current_user
    if @entertainment.save!
      redirect_to entertainments_path
      flash.notice = "Expense created successfully"
    else
      redirect_to root_path
      flash.alert = "Here's the error message"
    end
  end
```

The first part of the if-statement works fine (the instance `@entertainment` is created, and I see the flash notification). However the else-part does not work.

Here's my form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @entertainment do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :category, collection: Entertainment::CATEGORY, wrapper_html: {class: 'items-next'}, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :date_of_purchase, as: :date, html5: true, wrapper_html: {class: 'items-next'}, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :amount, placeholder: 'in euro', wrapper_html: {class: 'items-next'}, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :shop_name, wrapper_html: {class: 'items-next'} %>
    <%= f.input :description, wrapper_html: {class: 'items-next'} %>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Add expense', class: 'button-form' %>
  <% end %>
```

and my model:

```
class Entertainment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  CATEGORY = ['Gym', 'Yoga', 'Swimming pool', 'Cinema', 'Theater', 'Concert', 'Book', 'Magazine', 'Hobby', 'Hotel', 'Netflix/Amazon Prime', 'Other']
  CATEGORIES = CATEGORY.unshift(' ')
  validates :category, presence: true, inclusion: { in: CATEGORY }
  validates :date_of_purchase, presence: true
  validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
end
```

I tried also rendering the current view (`render :index`) in case of an error, but it does not work either.

Comment: I think the problem @entertainment.save! since you push to save it, you can use @entertainment.save

Comment: "else-part does not work" you have not shown what "does not work" means. If I had to guess it is because you are using `save!` (with a bang `!`) which raises an error if the model is invalid, just change this to `save`

Comment: "save" only (instead of "save!") works now, thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

`.save!` like the rest of the "bang" methods in `ActiveRecord::Persistence` will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotValid` exception if the validations fail.

While this is good for scenarios where saving the record should not be expected fail (like in a seed file) you want to use it's more gentle cousin `.save` in normal control flow when dealing with user input. After all users filling in a form inproperly is not an exceptional event.

Also you should NOT redirect if the form submission is not valid. All the input typed in by the user will disappear which makes for a really bad user expercience.

What I'm guesing you're doing here is that you're "embedding" the form in a view other the conventional `/entainments/new.html.erb`.

In that case you should either:

1. Render the same view that the form is placed on. This will require you to setup any instance variables or locals that this view needs to render.
2. Render a "new" view that just contains the form. Can be a slightly jarring user experience but doesn't require you to setup the dependencies of another controller/action's view.
3. Use Turbo to perform the operation without leaving the original page. You would render a partial with just the form on it (and some error messages) and Turbo replaces the original form in place.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and all the explanations! Everything is understood and I will correct my code accordingly.